# Simple way to make a file available to user for download

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a template xls file in the media folder. I want that the user can easily download this file from the page. What is a simple way of doing this?

I could not find any simple reliable way of doing this. Sorry, I'm new to Django.

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template:

```
...
<a href="#">Download Template</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`{% get_media_prefix %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix):

```
{% load static %}
<a href="{% get_media_prefix %}template.xls">Download Template</a>
```

Note that in production, media files are usually *not* served by Django, and you will thus need to configure nginx, etc. to serve the media files.

Comment: I get this error: 'get_media_prefix', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: @SumantAgnihotri: you likely have opened a block in your template that you forgot to close? Did you `{% load static %}`?

Comment: Fixed the error. I accidentally did `{% load staticfiles %}`